# Why are the androids so suprised when the machine lifeforms exhibit human traits?

Tags: nier-automata

9S keeps asking and wondering how the machines comprehend/possess human traits like loyalty or fear. I would understand his suprise if machines were built by humans before androids, but they were not. They were built by another species.

Why is it so strange that another entity is capable of these traits, if themselves are?

I have not finished the game, but this keeps bothering me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The traits you're mentioning are distinctly *human* traits. The reason it's surprising for a machine lifeform to be exhibiting these traits is precisely because of that fact.

The machine lifeforms are not human and were not created by humans, thus there should be no reason for them to be exhibiting human characteristics. Androids, however, *were* at least originally created by humans, so it would at least make *some* sense for them to exhibit these traits.

Comment: That makes sense, maybe the question now is why are they suprised and alien form share human traits, but i think ill may answer that playing. Thank you for your quick response @Vemonus

Comment: @Illiax no problem! As the story unfolds, this idea of "what makes something human" plays a huge role. I hope you enjoy the game!